# make same fab Transformation exapnd behavior like shown at material.io

Tags: java, android

I wanna have same fab transformation behavior as shown in 
[Material Website](https://material.io/design/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#types-of-transitions) in Full Screen (or morph) section.

I have tried default `FabTransformationScrimBehavior` and `FabTransformationSheetBehavior`. but scrim behavior doesn't do anything and sheet behavior don't animate just like I wanted and also it reduce the elevation of the fab to value `0f`. and I haven't found any way to unexpand fab. and I wanna know how to use fab transformation behavior. Actually I didn't find any doc on how to use it. So Please help

**Code**

This is the code that I used:

this is the code of first activity:-

```
final FloatingActionButton actionButton = findViewById(R.id.add_fab);
actionButton.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            actionButton.setExpanded(!actionButton.isExpanded());
        });
```

And this is the xml of first activity:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <include layout="@layout/include_generic_toolbar" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list_rv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="76dp"    
 app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
    tools:listitem="@layout/media_list_item_card" />

<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/add_fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="Add Media"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_24"/>

<com.google.android.material.circularreveal.CircularRevealFrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.transformation.FabTransformationSheetBehavior"
    >
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fab_transformation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.zimong.ssms.fragments.AddMediaFragment"
        />
</com.google.android.material.circularreveal.CircularRevealFrameLayout>
```

And the code of AddMediaFragment(second screen):- 
        package com.zimong.ssms.fragments;

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder;
import com.zimong.ssms.R;
import com.zimong.ssms.common.model.User;
import com.zimong.ssms.extended.CallbackHandlerImpl;
import com.zimong.ssms.model.Source;
import com.zimong.ssms.model.ZResponse;
import com.zimong.ssms.service.AppService;
import com.zimong.ssms.service.ServiceLoader;
import com.zimong.ssms.util.Constants;
import com.zimong.ssms.util.Util;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class AddMediaFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<Source> adapter;
    private TextView source;
    private int checkedItem = 0;
    private TextView mediaDate;
    private Date currentSelectedDate;


    public static AddMediaFragment newInstance() {
        AddMediaFragment fragment = new AddMediaFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.AppTheme_Light);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    private void getSources() {
        final User user = Util.getUser(getActivity());
        AppService service = ServiceLoader.createService(AppService.class);
        Call<ZResponse> call = service.mediaGallerySources(Constants.DEFAULT_PLATFORM, user.getToken());
        call.enqueue(new CallbackHandlerImpl<Source[]>(getActivity(), true, true, Source[].class) {
            @Override
            protected void failure(Throwable t) {

            }

            @Override
            protected void failure(Response<ZResponse> response) {

            }

            @Override
            protected void success(Source[] response) {
                if (response.length > 0) {
                    source.setText(response[0].getName());
                }
                adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Source>(getContext(), R.layout.dialog_singlechoice_item, response) {
                    @Override
                    public long getItemId(int position) {
                        return getItem(position).getPk();
                    }
                };


            }

        });
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_add_media, container, false);
        TextView headline = view.findViewById(R.id.media_headline);
        Toolbar toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getContext()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        source = view.findViewById(R.id.source);
        mediaDate = view.findViewById(R.id.media_date);
        Calendar fromDateInstance = Calendar.getInstance();
        currentSelectedDate = fromDateInstance.getTime();
        mediaDate.setText(Util.formatDate(fromDateInstance.getTime(), "dd MMM yyyy"));
        final DatePickerDialog fromDatePicker = new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), (datePicker, year, month, date) -> {
            fromDateInstance.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            fromDateInstance.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            fromDateInstance.set(Calendar.DATE, date);
            currentSelectedDate = fromDateInstance.getTime();
            mediaDate.setText(Util.formatDate(currentSelectedDate, "dd MMM yyyy"));
        }, fromDateInstance.get(Calendar.YEAR), fromDateInstance.get(Calendar.MONTH), fromDateInstance.get(Calendar.DATE));
        mediaDate.setOnClickListener(v -> fromDatePicker.show());
        source.setOnClickListener(v -> alertDialog());
        getSources();
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                getActivity().onBackPressed();
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void alertDialog() {
        MaterialAlertDialogBuilder builder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(getContext());
        builder.setTitle("Source");
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(adapter, checkedItem, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                source.setText(adapter.getItem(which).getName());
                checkedItem = which;
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

And the xml of Add Media is:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.circularreveal.coordinatorlayout.CircularRevealCoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/myCoordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$Behavior"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <include layout="@layout/include_toolbar" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>


    <include
        layout="@layout/content_add_media"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</com.google.android.material.circularreveal.coordinatorlayout.CircularRevealCoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: try https://medium.com/@lcdsmao/material-design-transition-for-floating-action-button-in-android-dc8304343cfe

Comment: @sowmia I already tried it. but it's not animating the way I want. fab goes to center and explode. and during animation fab elevation goes to zero. I don't want the fab to goes to center. actually I want the exact same animation as shown in material.io. I want my dialog fragment animate to full screen.

Comment: @sowmia. go to link in the post and see the full screen morphing

Comment: share your xml and code.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.circularreveal.CircularRevealLinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dial"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/fab"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="top|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.transformation.FabTransformationSheetBehavior">

        <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/back" 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/back"/>

    </com.google.android.material.circularreveal.CircularRevealLinearLayout>


    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

For the FabTransformationSheetBehavior to work, you need to change the **isExpanded** value. 
on change of this value, expand and collapse animation will be called and visibility of the linearlayout and fab button will be handled automatically. ***Don't change visibility manually as this would block transformation animation.***

Use back button to transform back to FAB.

```
val fab: FloatingActionButton = findViewById<FloatingActionButton>(R.id.fab)        
fab.setOnClickListener {  fab.isExpanded = !fab.isExpanded } // this sets isExpanded as true

val back = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.back)   
back.setOnClickListener{  fab.isExpanded = !fab.isExpanded } // this sets isExpanded as false
```